# Google Drive API returns 403 while uploading a file

Tags: javascript, angular, oauth, google-drive-api, google-oauth

Here is the code for uploading a file to Google dive after login.

```
var accessToken = this.userData.token; // Here gapi is used for retrieving the access token.
console.log("accessToken :: " + accessToken);
var form = new FormData();
form.append('metadata', new Blob([JSON.stringify(metadata)], {type: 'application/json'}));
form.append('file', file);

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
xhr.responseType = 'json';
console.log("XHR :: " + Object.values(xhr));
xhr.onload = () => {
    console.log(xhr.response.id); // Retrieve uploaded file ID.
};
xhr.send(file);
console.log("success.");
```

If I use the account which was used to generate the client_id and app_key, It is able to post the file data but If I use any other account it gives me error like below.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart&fields=id 403
```

I checked in the oAuth plaground with the same details and got response like this.

```
Www-authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error=insufficient_scope, scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Insufficient Permission", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global", 
        "message": "Insufficient Permission", 
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403, 
    "message": "Insufficient Permission", 
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "global", 
        "message": "Insufficient Permission", 
        "reason": "insufficientPermissions"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Has nothing to do with the client id.   When a user runs your application they are prompted to login to google and give your application consent to access their Google drive account.  You are given an accessToken that grants you access to their drive account.

`Insufficient Permission` means that the accessToken you have does not have the permission to do what it is you are trying to do.  I would check where it is you are trying to upload this file.

- Checked to be sure you are uploading it the currently authenticated users drive account and not the drive account of the first user?
- I cant see how you are authenticating the user make sure you are requesting one of the write scopes it could also be that you have requested the wrong scope.

Comment: Hi, I used the following link for login and getting the access token and I'm using the same token (this.userData.token) to authorization in header. I didn't use any scope.

Comment: Also, Why do I need file.ge()? I'm just uploading the file.

Comment: My mistake i thought you where updating the file itself.  I didnt realize it was a new file.   I would double check the scope you have used to authenticate this user.